# Having issues executing a makefile (run.sh) in git bash

Tags: windows, bash, visual-studio-code, git-bash

I am trying to use git bash to run my .sh file that was generated using Makefile.
When running the command `./run.sh` I get this message `./run.sh: line 1: /home/user/run: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

This error message says that the first line of the script tries to execute an executable program named `run` in your home directory, and this does not exist.

I don't know what `run.sh` is supposed to do, but if you want to execute it a program, you need to make sure that the program exists, for instance by creating it.

Comment: thanks. yes my makefile created a run file inside of my folder. I moved that file to my home directory and I was able to do ./run.sh

Answer (score 0):

To run a script file (using Git Bash), you do the following:

1. Add a "sh-bang" line on the first line (e.g. #!/bin/bash OR #!/usr/bin/env sh) this is how git bash knows a file is executable.
2. Use ./ (or any valid dir spec): ./script.sh

*Note : any "sh-bang" will work*

Comment: This advice would just shift the error message to line 2. Further, if the user wants run run the script using `sh`, a #! is not necessary. Of course if _bash_ should run it, you need one, or alternatively have to specify `bash` on invocation. However, this is unrelated to the problem posted here.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `git bash` so I suppose you are using Windows.

As for me I always use [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) on my scripts. Depending on the content of your script, you may add one of the following lines at the first line of your script.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/perl
#!/usr/bin/tcl
#!/bin/sed
#!/usr/awk
#!/usr/bin/python
```

If you still have problems running the script with `./run.sh` command, you may try to use `sh run.sh` (on Git bash) and it should execute the script just as `./run.sh` does it on linux.